NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest using Spring Framework version 5.1.3 to support PATCH
I am working on a Spring application using Spring Framework version 5.1.3.RELEAS and Java 1.8
I need to make a PATCH request, but I understand that RestTemplate does not natively support PATCH methods. To enable PATCH requests, I added the Apache HttpClient dependency to my pom.xml as follows:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

After adding this dependency, I configured RestTemplate to use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory:
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

However, when I try to run my application, I encounter the following exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest 


What is the correct version of Apache HttpClient to use with Spring Framework 5.1.3.RELEASE to avoid this issue?
Is there an alternative approach or workaround to support PATCH requests in this version of Spring?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
